# Calculo PBI datos no calu

Tags: powerbi, dax

tengo una consulta.

resulta que en un reporte que estoy haciendo se me pide crear una fuente de datos con la siguiente información, meta_px, meta_monto, fecha, sucursal, la idea es poder comparar lo facturado y la cantidad de pacientes atendidos por día, por código de clasificación.

resulta que la base de datos de las metas no existe y tuve que crearlas en un excel, la relación de las metas y la facturación la hice por código de clasificación.

el tema esta que a la hora de que se muestran los datos no me arrojan los datos correctos en cuanto las metas. al revisar el tipo de calculo que hace por defecto PBI lo hace por máximo en los campos de meta_px y meta_monto y no me arroja los datos correctos, existe alguna manera de que PBI no haga ningún calculo en esos dos campos antes mencionados.

PD: adjunto imágenes tanto del reporte donde se muestran los campos calculados como de la fuente de datos en excel.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFv6n.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Puedes cambiar la forma como un dato se agrega desde el lugar donde muestras que ahora está configurado como "Máximo". Pero también puedes decirle a Power BI que no realice nunca ningún cálculo con un campo determinado.

Para ello debes ir a la pestaña de "Modelado", seleccionar el campo y en "Resumen predeterminado" ponerlo en "No resumir".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: aunque sea una matriz